# multiple values in select option gives returned incorrect condition when comparing explode values

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have two select box with multiple values in each option which holds name and package amount of the user. before they can be able to merge a user for payment I need to make sure they merge users with the same package amount. But when i explode the values in each option and compare the package amount, it still gives me error even when the package amount are the same.

To make my explanation clear, here is a screenshot and the source codes:

[image]

The html source code:

```
<div class="row"> 
         <!-- BEGIN ALERT - REVENUE -->
         <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
          <p style="font-weight:bolder; font-size:16px;">New Members</p>

          <p>
          <select name="new_user" class="form-control">
           <option value="">New Members</option>
          <?php 
         $new = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM package");
         while($n = mysqli_fetch_array($new)){
          ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $n['username'] . "-" . $n['package_amount'];?>"><?php echo $n['username'];?> - <?php echo $n['package_amount'];?></option>

         <?php
         }
         ?>
          </select>
          </p>

        </div>
        <!--end .col --> 
        <!-- END ALERT - REVENUE --> 

        <!-- BEGIN ALERT - VISITS -->
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
           <p class="user-header" style="font-weight:bolder; font-size:16px;">Members Awaiting Payment</p>

          <p>
          <select name="awaiting_payment" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Awaiting Payment</option>
          <?php 
         $news = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM payment_queue");

         if(mysqli_num_rows($news) < 1){
            echo '<option value="">No Users Awaiting Payment at the Moment</option>'; 
         }else{
         while($n2 = mysqli_fetch_array($news)){
          ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $n2['username'] . "-" . $n2['package_amount'];?>"><?php echo $n2['username'];?> - <?php echo $n2['package_amount'];?></option>

         <?php
         }
         }
         ?>
          </select>
          </p>

      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
      <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div align="center"><button type="submit" name="submit" value="merge" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="fa fa-flag"></span> Merge</button></div>
      </div>
      </form>

</div>
```

And here is the processing source code:

```
// Manual Merging
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'merge') {
        //payee
        $value = $_POST['new_user'];    
        $payees = explode('-',$value);
        $name = $payees[0];
        $package = $payees[1];

        //collector
        $col = $_POST['awaiting_payment'];  
        $ap = explode('-',$col);
        $aname = $ap[0];
        $apn = $ap[1];

        if($_POST['new_user'] == "") {
            $newErr = "Select from new users a sponsor";
            $msgBox = alertBox($newErr, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else if($_POST['awaiting_payment'] == "") {
            $await = "Select member to be sponsor from awaiting payment list"; 
            $msgBox = alertBox($await, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        }//else if(!empty($_POST['new_user']) && !empty($_POST['awaiting_payment'])){
        else if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM to_be_paid WHERE username='".$_POST['awaiting_payment']."'"))>0){
        $user_error= $_POST['awaiting_payment']. " has already been assigned a member for payment";
        $msgBox = alertBox($user_error, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        }
        else if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM to_be_paid WHERE payee_username='".$_POST['new_user']."'"))>0){
        $user_e= $_POST['new_user']. " has already been assigned to pay.";
        $msgBox = alertBox($user_e, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        }       

        else if($package_name != $apn){
        $p_error= " The package of ". $package ." you are merging with " . $apn . " are not the same package. You need to merge package of the same denomination.";
        $msgBox = alertBox($p_error, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");   
        }



        //}
        else {
                //payee
                $value = $_POST['new_user'];    
                $payees = explode('-',$value);
                $name = $payees[0];
                $package = $payees[1];

                //collector
                $col = $_POST['awaiting_payment'];  
                $ap = explode('-',$col);
                $aname = $ap[0];
                $apn = $ap[1];
                //select from package table
                //This is the payee
                $paye =  mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM package WHERE username='$name' and package_amount= '$package'");
                $payee = mysqli_fetch_array($paye);

                //select from payment_queue table. This are people awaiting payment.

                $awaiting =  mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM payment_queue WHERE username='$aname' and package_amount='apn'");
                $await = mysqli_fetch_array($awaiting);

                //variable
                                $unames = $await['username'];
                                $ban = $await['bank_account_number'];
                                $pa = $await['package_amount'];
                                $puname = $payee['username'];
                                $ppn = $payee['phone_number'];
                                $pban = $payee['bank_account_name'];
                                $pbano = $payee['bank_account_number'];
                                $pbn = $payee['bank_name'];
                                $ppa = $payee['package_amount'];
                                //$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                                $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                                $tim = '+'.$set['donation_time'];
                                $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($tim.' hours', strtotime($now))); 

            //insert details into to_be_paid table

            $stmts = mysqli_query($mysqli, "
                                INSERT INTO
                                    to_be_paid( 
                                        username,
                                        bank_account_number,
                                        package_amount,
                                        payee_username,
                                        payee_number,
                                        payee_bank_account_name,
                                        payee_bank_account_number,
                                        payee_bank_name,
                                        payee_package_number,
                                        datetime
                                        ) VALUES (
                                        '$unames',
                                        '$ban',
                                        '$pa',
                                        '$puname',
                                        '$ppn',
                                        '$pban',
                                        '$pbano',
                                        '$pbn',
                                        '$ppa',
                                        '$date'

                                    )
            ");

                if($stmts){     
            //mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM package WHERE username='".$_POST['new_user']."'");

            $mergeOk = "Successfully Assigned " . $puname ." to ". $unames . " for Payment";
            $msgBox = alertBox($mergeOk, "<i class='fa fa-check-square'></i>", "success");
            //add to assign table
    mysqli_query($mysqli,
    "INSERT INTO 
    assign(
    username,
    bank_account_number,
    package_amount,
    payee_username,
    payee_bank_account_number

    ) 
    VALUES(
    '$unames',
    '$ban',
    '$pa',  
    '$puname', 
    '$pbano'
    )");

                    //delete person to be paid from payment_queue table
                    mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM payment_queue WHERE username='$aname' AND package_amount='$apn'");
                    //delete person to be paid from assign table
                    mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM assign WHERE username='$aname' AND package_amount='$apn'");

                }else{
                    $mergeErr = "There was an error assigning " . $puname ." to ". $unames . " for Payment. Please try again later.";
            $msgBox = alertBox($mergeErr, "<i class='fa fa-check-square'></i>", "danger");
                }

        }
    }
```

I have searched stackoverflow and online resources I could found but non was able to point me to the right path.

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
else if($package_name != $apn){
    $p_error= " The package of ". $package ." you are merging with " . $apn . " are not the same package. You need to merge package of the same denomination.";
    $msgBox = alertBox($p_error, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");   
    }
```

$package_name is not defined anywhere in your code.  Could it be $package instead?